# Git credential manager complains that my browser blocks cookies

Tags: windows, git, git-credential-manager

I am trying to manually clone a git repositories hosted in Azure DevOps as follows:

```
git clone https://<my-azure-devops-project>
```

but git credential manager complains that my browser is blocking cookies:

[Windows Credential Manager pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BByyh.png)

I checked my browser and cookies are enabled, even third-parties ones.
Is the credential manager really complaining about the Web Browser or is it something else ?

On the same machine, some Azure DevOps pipelines are running and they are able to clone the repositories without problem since a long time, either by letting the pipeline cloning the repository, or by cloning with my own script by providing my Personal Access Token like this:

```
git -c http.extraheader='AUTHORIZATION: bearer <PAT>' clone <REPO_URL>
```

Strangely, for one repository (a git lfs repo), if I switch branch from within the pipeline (after the repo was cloned with command above), the git Credential Manager cookies error pops up which make the pipeline stuck until I close the popup window. This was working fine for a long time.

The machine is running Windows Server 2019 and has been upgraded recently from Windows Server 2012. I am not completely sure but it seems that the problem appeared after the upgrade.

Here is the git config:

```
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
core.editor="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
```

I updated git with the latest version but it did not solve the problem.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.41.0.windows.1
```

Has anyone an idea one what is causing the Credential Manager cookies error popup ?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same type of problem on Windows Server 2019 and found a solution that works for me.

Try the following:

Click on the "Windows Start icon" and search for "Internet Properties" and open it. You'll get the window I show in the below image.

[image: Internet Properties image]

Disable "Enable Protected Mode" (circled in red in the image), log in to DevOps. Afterwards, Protected Mode can be re-enabled.

Comment: Thanks Janus. Unfortunately "Enable Protected Mode" is not there on my machine. May be because Internet Explorer is not installed (only Microsoft Edge is installed).

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get rid of the git credential manager pop-up complaining that cookies were blocked as follows:

1. In Windows, open "Internet Properties" and go to "Privacy", then "Advanced" and choose "Prompt" so that you are prompted to allow cookies.

[image: Internet Properties / Privacy]

2. Run git clone and answer yes when prompted for cookies.
3. In Internet Properties you will see a new entry in "Privacy" / "Sites".

[image]

4. In "Privacy" / "Advanced", reset how cookies are handled to their original value ("Accept" in my case).